# 3D Top-Down Несколько вопросов по контроллеру персонажа

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уважаемые друзья, имеется игра с видом сверху, top-down 3D, рпг, но с управление как в шутере (non-target). Пока ещё реализована только моделька игрока с анимациями и некоторым шмотом. Застрял на управлении и никак не могу сдвинуться уже третью неделю. Перепробовал и рутмоушн, и чарактер контроллер. Есть несколько проблем:
Управление WASD, персонаж смотрит на курсор, но двигается по мировым координатам (W -> бежит строго север). Анимации блендятся хорошо.

1. Не могу поменять скорость для движения задним ходом и боковым ходом. Куда писать и что конкретно?
2. Если я хочу сделать дополнительную анимацию удара, прыжка, бега спринтом - лучше это делать через IK?
3. Когда в Update меняю то, что там сейчас на
   transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed);
   transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed);

Для игрока перед становится там, где курсор т.е. W -> бежит в сторону курсора, а не "на север". Но почему-то полностью пропадает коллизия с террейном, объектами. Т.е. capsule collider будто перестает существовать, хотя игрок "под землю" не проваливается. Из-за чего так?

4. Персонаж падает вначале очень медленно, но со временем ускоряется. Но сначала будто в воздухе летит несколько секунд. Из-за чего так? Нереалистично.
5. Если я хочу всё же сделать так, чтобы персонаж бежал вперед именно в сторону курсора (что упростило бы анимации) - так было бы правильнее? Удобнее? Как тогда подкорректировать код, чтобы перед для персонажа был там, где курсор? Как сделать так, чтобы анимации блендились уже с учетом этого направления?
6. Анимации ударов, стрельбы при каком управлении будет проще прикрутить, как и саму стрельбу с ударами?

Вот кодик:

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("Скорость:")]
    public float speed = 4f;
    public float acceleration = 10f;
    public float RunSpeed = 3f;
            
    [Header("Поворот:")]
    public Transform bodyTransform; 
    public float smooth = 3;
    public bool useSmooth;

    //private float gravityForce;

    [Header("Скрипт контроля камеры")]
    public Transform cameraParent;
    
    private Vector3 direction;
    private Rigidbody body;
    public Animator _anim;
    private float vertical;
    private float horizontal;
    Vector3 camForward;
    Vector3 move;
    Vector3 moveInput;
    Transform Cam;

    float forwardAmount;
    float turnAmount;

    void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        body.freezeRotation = true;
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        
        Cam = Camera.main.transform;
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
    vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if(Cam != null)
        {
            camForward = Vector3.Scale(Cam.up, new Vector3(1,0,1)).normalized;
            move = vertical * camForward + horizontal * Cam.right;
        }
        else 
        {
            move = vertical * Vector3.forward + horizontal * Vector3.right;
        }

        if (move.magnitude > 1)
        {
            move.Normalize();
        }
        Move(move);

        body.AddForce(direction.normalized * acceleration * body.mass * speed);
        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > speed)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector3(Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.x) * speed, body.velocity.y, body.velocity.z);
        }
        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.z) > speed)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector3(body.velocity.x, body.velocity.y, Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.z) * speed);
        }
        Rotation();
        
    }
    void Move(Vector3 move)
    {
        if(move.magnitude > 1)
        {
            move.Normalize();
        }
        this.moveInput = move;
        ConvertMoveInput();
        UpdateAnimator();
    }

    void ConvertMoveInput()
    {
        Vector3 localMove = transform.InverseTransformDirection(moveInput);
        forwardAmount = localMove.z;
        turnAmount = localMove.x;
    }

    void UpdateAnimator()
    {
        _anim.SetFloat("Forward", forwardAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
        _anim.SetFloat("Turn", turnAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void Rotation() 
    {
        Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.y)) - body.position;
        lookPos.y = 0; 

        if(useSmooth)
        {
            Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
            bodyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(bodyTransform.rotation, playerRotation, smooth * Time.fixedDeltaTime); 
        }
        else
        {
            bodyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        direction = new Vector3(h, 0, v);
        direction = cameraParent.TransformDirection(direction);
        direction = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z);
    }
}
```

P.S. Я начинающий кодер с знаниями основ, но в геймдеве больше как моделлер и композитор музыки. Поэтому не всё прям соображаю в коде. Прочитать - могу, а вот написать с нуля - это пока что не досягаемая вершина.